# Optional parameter in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

i am using optional parameter in the following code. but that shows error "default parameter specifiers are not permitted"  anybody help me sir.

```
public void getno(int pvalu, string pname = "")
{

}
```

Answer (score 25):

It looks like there's some misinformation in some of the answers:

- Optional parameters were introduced into C# 4, so you *must* use the C# 4 compiler
- Optional parameters have been in the *framework* forever, so you can target *any* version of the framework and still use them, so long as you're using the C# 4 compiler. It's entirely reasonable to target .NET 2 with the C# 4 compiler, and then someone referencing your library from, say, VB8 would still be able to use your optional parameters.

As others have stated, overloads are an alternative to using optional parameters if you're not using C# 4 or if you want your code to be *consumed* by earlier C# code. (If you build a library using C# 4 but then some C# 3 code needs to call into it, those optional parameters are effectively going to be required as far as that code is concerned.)

(As an aside, I would seriously reconsider your names... I know this is only sample code, but generally speaking prefixes like "p" for parameters are discouraged as a matter of convention, and likewise methods are generally Pascal-cased.)

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to do this using MonoDevelop?

Comment: @LeaHayes: I'd expect MonoDevelop to support C# 4 by now. Probably best just to try it.

Comment: The problem is that Unity only supports the 2.0. Whilst targeting 4.0 runtime does seem to work, apparently Unity uses the 2.0 runtime only and some people suggest using .NET 3.5 framework instead (2.0 runtime). But with .NET 3.5 selected, MonoDevelop doesn't allow the optional parameters.

Comment: @LeaHayes: You need to differentiate between *language* and *framework* features. Optional parameters have been in the .NET framework since 1.0, it's just that C# hasn't supported it before. If MonoDevelop refuses to support C# 4 features which can be supported by the runtime in question, that sounds like a bug to me.

Answer (score 7):

Try overloading the method rather

```
    public void getno(int pvalu)
    {
        getno(pvalu, "");
    }

    public void getno(int pvalu, string pname)
    {

    }
```

Have a look at [Method Usage Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxfyae0c(VS.71).aspx)

See also for .Net 4 [Named and Optional Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

Comment: Then you will have to stick to method overloading as illustrated.

Comment: Because of this one example, I now understand method overloading...  lmao~

Answer (score 2):

Optional parameters have been introduced in C# 4.0 - what version are you using?

VB.NET has always had optional parameters.

You can always use overloads and method chaining to gain similar capabilities:

```
public void getno(int pvalu)
{
   getno(pvalue, "");
}


public void getno(int pvalu, string pname)
{

}
```

Comment: They were introduced in C# 4, but have been in .NET since 1.0. See my answer.

Comment: @Jon - yes, I was thinking about C#, VB.NET always had them. Answer updated.

Comment: @user443099 - _what_ is not supported?

Comment: @user443099 - C# 4.0 and any version of vb.net has support for optional parameters. I don't understand what you are talking about. Please be specific.

Comment: public void getno(int pvalu, string pname="") 
    { 
 
    } 
this function shows error ( near = symbol)

Comment: @user443099 - Then you are not using a C# 4.0 compiler, as other answers has noted.

Answer (score 1):

Are you compiling with the .NET 4 compiler (e.g. VS 2010) as only this compiler supports optional parameters for C#?

Personally I would overload the method rather than use optional parameters for methods that I was creating, reserving using optional parameters for use with API calls where there is a large number of default values.

*Thanks to Jon Skeet for clarifying the difference between targeting .NET 4 and using the .NET 4 compiler.*

Comment: It's only a new *language* feature - it doesn't need .NET 4. See my answer.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Cheers for clarifying that.

Answer (score 0):

Optional parameters are supported in C# from version 4, make sure your project is set to compile using the C# 4 compiler.

Comment: You don't need to be compiling against .NET 4 - but you *do* need to use the C# 4 compiler.

Comment: @user443099: Which version of Visual Studio are you using though? The target framework is irrelevant - it's the *compiler* which is important.

Comment: @user443099: In that case you're using the C# 3.0 compiler, which doesn't support optional parameters.