# Default parameter specifiers are not permitted error on C#

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, default-parameters

When I build my project, VC# says Default parameter specifiers are not permitted. And it leads me to this code:

```
public class TwitterResponse
{
    private readonly RestResponseBase _response;
    private readonly Exception _exception;

    internal TwitterResponse(RestResponseBase response, Exception exception = null)
    {
        _exception = exception;
        _response = response;
    }
```

What could be my mistake?

Comment: What's the error message exactly? Which line?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio and which .NET framework are you using?  Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7822450/76217) help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822450/default-parameter-specifiers-are-not-permitted

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203959/optional-parameter-in-c-sharp

Comment: You should accept the answer if it was useful!! or put a comment to see where is the problem with the answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mistake is:

```
Exception exception = null
```

You can move to C# 4.0 or later, this code will compile!

This question will help you:

[C# 3.5 Optional and DefaultValue for parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116340/c-sharp-3-5-optional-and-defaultvalue-for-parameters)

Or you can make two overrides to solve this on C# 3.0 or earlier:

```
public class TwitterResponse
{
    private readonly RestResponseBase _response;
    private readonly Exception _exception;

    internal TwitterResponse(RestResponseBase response): this(response, null)
    {

    }

    internal TwitterResponse(RestResponseBase response, Exception exception)
    {
        _exception = exception;
        _response = response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if you are using .NET 3.5.  Optional parameters were introduced in C# 4.0.

```
internal TwitterResponse(RestResponseBase response, Exception exception = null)
{
    _exception = exception;
    _response = response;
}
```

Should be:

```
internal TwitterResponse(RestResponseBase response, Exception exception)
{
    _exception = exception;
    _response = response;
}
```

Note how there is no default value for the `exception` variable.